# How to use only one access and leave the other usable for other scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector-graphics, quaternions

Don't know a really good title for this, I have a rotation for the camera on two scripts. One for the Y axis for the player rotation and one for the X axis for the camera rotation.

I use a `transform.rotation` value on the Camera rotation, because I want to clamp it which is not possible with 
`transform.Rotate` although, when I put in
`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (mRotX, transform.rotation.y,transform.rotation.z);` it locks the y rotation to 0 while still trying to move the camera by the player.

Now for my question, how do I only access one axis and leave the other axis' usable for other scripts?

Comment: If you remove `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (mRotX, transform.rotation.y,transform.rotation.z);` line it works correctly? and when you add this line it stops from work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by you misteaking the Quaternion as euler angles. Your new rotation should be constructed like this:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler( mRotX, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z );
```

In other words, for constructing Quaternion from Euler you need to pass euler arguments (rotation.eulerAngles), not the x,y,z,w from quaternion which are totally different thing.

For more information see the Quaternion.Euler and eulerAngles at unity3D docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html

Hope that it solves your problem.